# Is there a cleaner/simpler way for writing this formula in code?

Tags: java, math, double, bigdecimal

I need to return a double value.
This value is derived from this formula.

monthly interest = balance * interest rate / 100.00 /12.0

Due to some precision issues, I am to use BigDecimal during calculation and return a double value (as this is how money is represented).

I've tried the code below and it works perfectly okay but looks quite long and a bit unreadable if you ask me.

```
double bal = 10, rate=2, hundred = 100.00, month = 12.0;

double monthInt= (BigDecimal.valueOf(bal).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(rate)).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(hundred)).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(month))).doubleValue();

return monthInt;
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate for an entire year always or is there a possibility of providing `month = 11.0` and by doing so calculating the interest for January to November only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that the result of `balance * interest rate` will always be divided by `100` and `12`. So you could save these static parts of your formula in a `static` variable.

```
private static final BigDecimal MONTH_IN_PERCENT = BigDecimal.valueOf(100 * 12);
```

And then use that in your computation:

```
return BigDecimal.valueOf(bal).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(rate).divide(MONTH_IN_PERCENT).doubleValue();
```

And if you can guarantee that `bal * rate <= Long.MAX_VALUE`, you can use this version:

```
return BigDecimal.valueOf((long) bal * rate).divide(MONTH_IN_PERCENT).doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advice you to add some precision to your `BigDecimal`-divisions. Otherwise you may get some `ArithmeticException` stating that no exact precision was provided.

Do something like this

```
public static double calculateMonthlyInterest(BigDecimal balance, BigDecimal rate,
               BigDecimal hundred, BigDecimal month) {
    return balance.multiply(rate)
            .divide(hundred, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
            .divide(month, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
            .doubleValue();
}
```

Or this (if you want to provide `double` parameters):

```
public static double calculateMonthlyInterest(double balance, double rate,
               double hundred, double month) {
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(balance);
    BigDecimal r = new BigDecimal(rate);
    BigDecimal h = new BigDecimal(hundred);
    BigDecimal m = new BigDecimal(month);
    return b.multiply(r)
            .divide(h, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
            .divide(m, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
            .doubleValue();
}
```

This way, the code stays readable but that comes to a certain price: There are more lines of code!